# How to bring JPGraph second Y-axis data in front (AddY2)?

Tags: php, graph, jpgraph

I have this JPGraph (with proper data):

```
// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(640,350,"auto");
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->SetY2Scale("lin",0,100);

// Create the bar graph
$bplot1 = new BarPlot($datay);
$bplot1->SetFillGradient("darkolivegreen1","darkolivegreen4",GRAD_VERT);
$bplot1->SetWeight(0);
$graph->Add($bplot1);

// Create the line graph
$lplot = new LinePlot($datay2);
$lplot->SetBarCenter();
$lplot->SetStepStyle();
$graph->AddY2($lplot);

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
```

This works fine (at least it shows the correct data) but my problem is that the Y2 data is behind the bars. I want the Y2 data in front so the data can be shown with a light opacity and I can see how many percent it is.

I have tried rearranging the code so the AddY2 came first or last and even mixed it, but still the same - always behind the bars.

Anyone having any insights on this?

If this is not doable, what is the alternative then - any other free graph tools out there that works just as great as JPGraph (I use CentOS and PHP)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking to achieve ... Try flipping around the Y scales.

`$graph->Add($bplot1);` to `$graph->AddY2($bplot1);`

and

`$graph->AddY2($lplot);` becomes `$graph->Add($lplot);`

**EDIT:**

As I misunderstood... Add `$graph->SetY2OrderBack(false);` will place Y2 on the foreground of Y1.
**Source:** [docs/classref/Graph.html#_GRAPH_SETY2ORDERBACK](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/Graph.html#_GRAPH_SETY2ORDERBACK)

Comment: No, that is not an option as the $bplot1 graph is the primary graph. Switching the graphs will confuse the reader as you always have the most important graph on the left Y-axis.

Comment: `$graph->SetY2OrderBack(false);`

Comment: Great - the "$graph->SetY2OrderBack(false);" fixed it and the Y2 is now in front. Thanks a lot.